# Can you use display: table / table-cell to vertical-align text over a responsive image (with auto height)?

Tags: css

I have an image that takes up the fold, below a fixed nav. I Want to vertical align: middle the #fold-text and chevron over the image.

html markup:

```
<div class="row">
  <img class="background-image" src="images/1400px_splash.jpeg">
    <div id="fold-container">
      <div id="fold-text">
        Sign up to learn about upcoming changes!
      </div>
      <div class="fa fa-chevron-down"></div>
    </div>
  </img>
</div>
```

This CSS below usually works when I want to center one div within another, but not luck on this (maybe because the img height is set to "auto" ? ) . Can anyone tell me how to correct this?

```
.background-image {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}

#fold-container {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

  #fold-text {
    font-size: 1.6em;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: rgba(black, 0.3);
    color: white;
    display: table-cell;
  }

  .fa.fa-chevron-down {
    z-index: 500;
    color:white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: normal;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: Can you share with us the real `html`? Or even better, add a snippet to your question so we could actually see your wish?

Comment: converted. I'll try to get a plunkr up when I get back home in a few.

Comment: Are you trying to add text *inside* an image tag?  Because that's not the way image tags work.  They don't contain any other elements or text, they are just the image itself.

Comment: Trying to overlap and center text on top of the image, with the text being vertically aligned to the middle of the image.  Usually, I set the parent div to display table, then the text within to display table-cell. But, it seems you're saying I cannot have an element that's a child of the image?

Comment: @someoneHere Correct, that's what I'm saying, [see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img), specifically "Permitted content: None, it is an empty element." and "Tag omission: Must have a start tag and must not have an end tag."  See my answer below for how the browser is actually behaving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your desired markup:

```
<div class="row">
  <img class="background-image" src="images/1400px_splash.jpeg">
    <div id="fold-container">
      <div id="fold-text">
        Sign up to learn about upcoming changes!
      </div>
      <div class="fa fa-chevron-down"></div>
    </div>
  </img>
</div>
```

... is not valid HTML.  `<img>` tags don't contain any other markup, so what the browser sees is more like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <!-- note the self closing img tag -->
  <img class="background-image" src="images/1400px_splash.jpeg"/>
  <div id="fold-container">
    <div id="fold-text">
      Sign up to learn about upcoming changes!
    </div>
    <div class="fa fa-chevron-down"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- </img> don't know what to do with this, because img tags close themselves -->
</div>
```

What you need to do is more like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div id="fold-container">
    <div id="fold-text">
      Sign up to learn about upcoming changes!
    </div>
    <div class="fa fa-chevron-down"></div>
    <img class="background-image" src="images/1400px_splash.jpeg"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

... and just make sure the appropriate stylings are added to your elements to position them appropriately.